# Modal View Controller force Landscape orientation in iOS 6

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a UITabBarController presented in Portrait mode. On one of the tabs I have a button that shows a UIViewController modally (A simple storyboard segue performs the action).

I want this modal view to be shown in Landscape mode, but I can't get it to turn automatically.

I have this in the modal views controller

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

I've added landscapeLeft to the .plist supported orientations (although this also allows the TabBar to be rotated which I don't want)

I've also added this to the ViewDidLoad of the modal view

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
```

but I just can't get it to rotate by itself.

Thanks

EDIT ----

It seems shouldAutoRotate isn't even being called!

Also, I'm trying to detect the orientation and this code below always shows 2, regardless of orientation!

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        NSLog(@"1");
        self.hostView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, 200, 255);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"2");
        self.hostView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 45, 480, 255);
    }
```

EDIT 2 ---

My bad. I guess I should have mentioned I was using iOS 6. The display rotates automatically on iOS 5.
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is deprecated so I need to read up on the new methods.

Comment: from my previous experience with this, there is no way to force a viewController to appear in a specific orientation. You can choose whether you allow the orientation to change or not, but not force it. it was a bummer for me...

Comment: Thats a bit stupid really! I have a graph that will only fit in Landscape. So you saying Apple wants me to show it screwed up until the user turns his device. That doesn't sound right, although I haven't found a solution so you may be right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> iOS 6.0 Release Notes 
>   *"More responsibility is moving to the app and the app delegate. Now, iOS containers (such as UINavigationController) do not consult their children to determine whether they should autorotate. "*

`-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate` of UIViewController under any Container (like UINavigationController) will not be called from IOS6.

Tried a solution with using Category to add method to existing UINavigationController Class.

inside the **shouldAutorotate** method, you can call shouldAutorotate method in each view controller of self.viewControllers. In fact, you can pass to your child view controller.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to force rotation in iOS6, your rootviewController should implement these methods:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 6 it seems to be this method may help force a specific orientation on iOS 6.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

I am still trying to get it to work and will update with any findings.

Comment: Thanks, it works in my case together with the method -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{ return NO;}

Answer (score 0):

I do exactly this in my app, and do it via shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation, slightly differently than you:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
 if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))
  return (YES);
 return (NO);
}
```

for iOS 6, you must also set window.rootViewController = {your root view controller}; in your app delegate.  I'm hoping this is your issue

Comment: This still doesn't force the orientation. I've added this to my AppDelegate
self.window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainTab"];

Comment: ok bummer, I'm not using storyboards in my apps, though I wouldn't think that should cause this issue.  I suspect the rootViewController property is being set for you automatically anyhow.  It would be interesting to log calls to shouldAutorotate to see if its even getting called

Comment: No, shouldAutorotate isn't being called at all!

Comment: Oops. shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is deprecated in iOS 6. I guess I should have mentioned I was using it.