# how to change screen orientation on new modal view controller iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, orientation

I have an app developed for iPhone with Xcode which diplays my view controllers in portrait mode with rotation activated.

there's a cell in my table view  which triggers a new view controller (iPhoneSignVC) in modal mode, my question is...

is there a way to determine my new modal view controller's orientation from the very begining?? I mean... I want my new view controller to be in landscape mode and without screen rotation feature activated on that particular viewController

so far what I did was to create a new Class which overwrites UINavigation controller's class

```
#import "UINavigationController.h"
#import "iPhoneSignVC.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (overrides)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    id currentViewController = self.topViewController;

    if ([currentViewController isKindOfClass:[iPhoneSignVC class]])
        return NO;


    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    id currentViewController = self.topViewController;

    if ([currentViewController isKindOfClass:[iPhoneSignVC class]]){
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
    }

    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}


@end
```

I tried this without success...

Thanks in advance for your support folks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is all you need for your modal view to open in the orientation you want:

```
#import "UINavigationController.h"
#import "iPhoneSignVC.h"


@implementation UINavigationController (overrides)

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    if ([self.topViewController isKindOfClass:[iPhoneSignVC class]])
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple considerations that go into this depending on underlying OS.
Checkout this [very comprehensive question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716495/force-landscape-mode-at-the-beginning-of-app-but-allow-later-changes-in-orienta?lq=1) and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434992/supporting-both-ios-6-and-ios-5-autorotation).

Comment: You've posted links to a question which accepted answer is more links. Try to post an answer instead of links as if the links change then the answer is useless